# Draw multiple rectangle on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add multiple rectangle on canvas on mouse move. But when I am drawing rectangle on image, back image on canvas is also cleared. I don't want to remove it. I want multiple rectangle on  canvas without clearing canvas image. Please check below JavaScript code.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasarea'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
         base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg'; //Load Image ;
base_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(base_image,0,0);
}
var strokeWidth = 4;
drawCount = 1;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                    drawRectangleOnCanvas.handleMouseMove(e);
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
                    drawRectangleOnCanvas.handleMouseDown(e);
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
                    drawRectangleOnCanvas.handleMouseUp(e);
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
                 drawRectangleOnCanvas.handleMouseOut(e);
            }, false);

function reOffset(){
              var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
              recOffsetX=BB.left;
              recOffsetY=BB.top;        
            }
            var recOffsetX,recOffsetY;
            reOffset();
            window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
            window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

            var isRecDown=false;
            var startX,startY;

            var rects=[];
            var newRect;
var drawRectangleOnCanvas={
                handleMouseDown:function(e){
                  // tell the browser we're handling this event
                  e.preventDefault();
                  e.stopPropagation();

                  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-recOffsetX);
                  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-recOffsetY);

                  // Put your mousedown stuff here
                  isRecDown=true;
                },

                handleMouseUp:function(e){
                  // tell the browser we're handling this event
                  e.preventDefault();
                  e.stopPropagation();

                  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-recOffsetX);
                  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-recOffsetY);

                  // Put your mouseup stuff here
                  isRecDown=false;

                  //if(!willOverlap(newRect)){
                    rects.push(newRect);
                  //}
                  drawRectangleOnCanvas.drawAll();
                },

                drawAll:function(){
                  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                  context.lineWidth=strokeWidth;
                  //context.strokeStyle=$('div.dropdown-menu').find('.selected').attr('data-color');
                  for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
                    var r=rects[i];
                    context.strokeStyle = r.color;
                    context.globalAlpha=1;
                    context.strokeRect(r.left,r.top,r.right-r.left,r.bottom-r.top);

                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc(r.left, r.top, 15, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
                    context.closePath();
                    context.fillStyle = r.color;
                    context.fill();

                    var text = drawCount;
                    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
                    var font = "bold " + 2 +"px serif";
                    context.font = font;
                    var width = context.measureText(text).width;
                    var height = context.measureText("w").width; // this is a GUESS of height
                    context.fillText(text, r.left - (width/2) ,r.top + (height/2));

                  }
                },

                handleMouseOut:function(e){
                  // tell the browser we're handling this event
                  e.preventDefault();
                  e.stopPropagation();

                  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-recOffsetX);
                  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-recOffsetY);

                  // Put your mouseOut stuff here
                  isRecDown=false;
                },

                handleMouseMove:function(e){
                  if(!isRecDown){return;}
                  // tell the browser we're handling this event
                  e.preventDefault();
                  e.stopPropagation();

                  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-recOffsetX);
                  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-recOffsetY);
                  newRect={
                    left:Math.min(startX,mouseX),
                    right:Math.max(startX,mouseX),
                    top:Math.min(startY,mouseY),
                    bottom:Math.max(startY,mouseY),
                    color:"#000000"
                  }
                  drawRectangleOnCanvas.drawAll();
                  context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
                  context.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
                  context.globalAlpha=1;
                  context.strokeRect(startX,startY,mouseX-startX,mouseY-startY);
                }
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvasarea"></canvas>
```

Comment: I am able to draw multiple ractangle on your canvas:- Version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @AlivetoDie Mulitple rectangles working but when we create rectangle back image on canvas is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clearing the canvas you need to draw the image as well in your `drawAll()` method.  `context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasarea'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var base_image = new Image();
base_image.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg'; //Load Image ;
base_image.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
}

function drawImage() {
}
var strokeWidth = 4;
drawCount = 1;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  drawRectangleOnCanvas.handleMouseMove(e);
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  drawRectangleOnCanvas.handleMouseDown(e);
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  drawRectangleOnCanvas.handleMouseUp(e);
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
  drawRectangleOnCanvas.handleMouseOut(e);
}, false);

function reOffset() {
  var BB = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  recOffsetX = BB.left;
  recOffsetY = BB.top;
}
var recOffsetX, recOffsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  reOffset();
}
window.onresize = function(e) {
  reOffset();
}

var isRecDown = false;
var startX, startY;

var rects = [];
var newRect;
var drawRectangleOnCanvas = {
  handleMouseDown: function(e) {
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - recOffsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - recOffsetY);

    // Put your mousedown stuff here
    isRecDown = true;
  },

  handleMouseUp: function(e) {
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - recOffsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - recOffsetY);

    // Put your mouseup stuff here
    isRecDown = false;

    //if(!willOverlap(newRect)){
    rects.push(newRect);
    //}
    drawRectangleOnCanvas.drawAll();
  },

  drawAll: function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
    context.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
    for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
      var r = rects[i];
      context.strokeStyle = r.color;
      context.globalAlpha = 1;
      context.strokeRect(r.left, r.top, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top);

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(r.left, r.top, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      context.closePath();
      context.fillStyle = r.color;
      context.fill();

      var text = drawCount;
      context.fillStyle = "#fff";
      var font = "bold " + 2 + "px serif";
      context.font = font;
      var width = context.measureText(text).width;
      var height = context.measureText("w").width; // this is a GUESS of height
      context.fillText(text, r.left - (width / 2), r.top + (height / 2));

    }
  },

  handleMouseOut: function(e) {
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - recOffsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - recOffsetY);

    // Put your mouseOut stuff here
    isRecDown = false;
  },

  handleMouseMove: function(e) {
    if (!isRecDown) {
      return;
    }
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - recOffsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - recOffsetY);
    newRect = {
      left: Math.min(startX, mouseX),
      right: Math.max(startX, mouseX),
      top: Math.min(startY, mouseY),
      bottom: Math.max(startY, mouseY),
      color: "#000000"
    }
    drawRectangleOnCanvas.drawAll();
    context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    context.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
    context.globalAlpha = 1;
    context.strokeRect(startX, startY, mouseX - startX, mouseY - startY);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvasarea"></canvas>
```

Comment: Its working fine for me, chrome Version 63.0.3239.108 and on mozilla as well

Comment: Thanks for the solution its working. But is there any another solution without redrawing it again.

Comment: @AjayThakur need to redraw again

Comment: @AjayThakur You have to redraw as the canvas is getting cleared

Comment: @Durga main problem is i have another shapes also on canvas. After redrawing it that shapes removed

Comment: @AjayThakur See as you are drawing rectangles like that redraw all the shapes.

Comment: @Durga Can you help me in this post also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145907/show-points-on-canvas